# Populating Spinner from datasbase ina android

Tags: android

i m trying to display a list of sessions stored in `database` into a `Spinner` with the help of `SimpleCursorAdapter`. some how not able to do so

```
Cursor cs=db.getAllSession();
String[] from=new String[]{"sess_name"};        
int[] to=new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cs, from, to );
adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

session table has two fields `id` and `sess_name`.
i m getting illegal argument exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.world.shaman/com.world.shaman.Test}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

i dont know wats the problem

[image]

Comment: can you show getAllSession() method in your DB helper?

Answer (score 1):

As biegleux said, the cursor needs to have an `_id` column for the spinner to work.

This does not necessarily mean you need to change the column name in your DB.  That would be the recommened way, but you could also modify your query to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT id AS _id, sess_name FROM your_table
```

Comment: thanks barak :) its working.i changed the column id.but can u tell me how to such a select query in android as u have suggested??

Answer (score 0):

Use `_id` as a name of your column in your `session` table instead of `id`.

From [CursorAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html):

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not
>   work.